# Android invoke interface inside class file in lib module

Tags: android, interface

Hi in my lib module I'm having a interface like this,

```
public interface ServiceData {
    void deviceName();
}
```

I implement this in Main app module in Activity as follows,

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServiceData

    @Override
    public void deviceName() {

    }

}
```

I have to invoke this in a class file which is also in lib module. I searched and found solution like

```
ServiceData service = (ServiceData) context;
```

But it throws `ClassCastException`. How can I invoke this in a class file? Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously `context` is not an instance of `MainActivity` nor any `ServiceData` implementation... you cannot cast some random `Context` to `ServiceData`

Comment: Okay,thank you.How can I invoke interface?

Comment: to invoke **deviceName()** you will need your interface object reference.

Comment: try ServiceData service = this;  and pass that to the class where you are invoking it, then call service.deviceName

Comment: @George Thomas it also throws CCE.

Comment: @Nishant Pardamwar yes that is my problem. How can I create interface object reference.

Comment: can you update the question and show how and where u have implemented it

Comment: Wait I update my question, because I have created interface in library module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localbroadcastmanager.
 In lib

Intent intent = new Intent("YOUR_INFO");

```
LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
manager.sendBroadcast(intent);

In app.

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("YOUR_INFO");

LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
manager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("MainActivity","your info" +"  "+action);
        if(action.equals("YOUR_INFO")) {

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you,it works. But why cannot we achieve this via interface.